# Creating a directory shortcut in powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm writing my first powershell script and I'm having a little trouble.

Up to this point my system creates a directory tree and populates it with files. The final step is to put a shortcut on my desktop.

I've come up with the code below:

```
$ShortcutFile = "$home\Desktop\" + $protocol + ".lnk"
If ( (test-path -path "$ShortcutFile") -ne $true)
{
    $WScriptShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
    $Shortcut = $WScriptShell.CreateShortcut($ShortcutFile)
    $Shortcut.TargetPath = $root_path
    $Shortcut.Save()
}
```

This doesn't work as I'm sure any experienced powershell user knows. A file is created rather than a directory. I imagine the correct way to fix this is to change one of the object members in WScript.Shell which control's the file type. I have had no luck locating any resources on how to do this specifically, or any other way to go about doing it. I found the API on the MSDN website but there where only a few members listed. There must be more.
What is the best way to accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Shortcut that points to folder named the current date. YYYY\_MM\_DD Format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16469899/shortcut-that-points-to-folder-named-the-current-date-yyyy-mm-dd-format)

Comment: *A file is created rather than a directory.* Not sure what you mean by that, shortcut is a file even if it point to directory. I does not see any problem with your code. If I define `$protocol='SomeName';$root_path='C:\'`, than your code work without any problems.

Comment: No brianist. That post discusses creating a file. Not a directory.

Comment: When I use that code I get a file that windows doesn't know how to open. When I look at it under properties the type is listed as a file. If you make a shortcut from a folder the type is listed as"file folder"

Comment: @mreff555 Are you sure that `$root_path` points to existing directory? BTW use `@UserName` to notify user of your comment.

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine for me on Windows 7/PS 4.0.  What value does `$ShortcutFile` have?  What does `Test-Path $ShortcutFile -IsValid` return?  Are you expecting shortcuts to be navigable from the command line like NTFS junctions are?

Comment: Yes I'm sure $root_path points to a directory. I have attached my entire source to the question.

Comment: On Win7, PS5, your code works as PetSerAl said, just by supplying values for $protocol and $root_path.  The only thing out of the ordinary I see is that the icon is not a folder icon.  But looking at the properties of the .lnk file everything else is as expected and if I double-click it takes me to $root_path.  Can you tell us what the Type column says in explorer for the .lnk file created on your PC?

Comment: I can confirm what @mreff555 is saying,I have the same issue, while creating shortcuts on server remotely. If I create shortcut to C:\ it works fine but fails for any other folder. "file" looking like shortcut is created - checking properties and it looks like shortcut, everything is fine there. What is going on ? Did you ever figure it out ?

Comment: No I was never able to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you mean the shortcut type is a `File` rather than a `File folder` then a workaround is to make an `Application` launcher instead, which always works.

I originally found this solution [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/fae0df7f-e905-4446-850c-b5109bb20428/creating-network-folder-shortcut-using-script?forum=ITCG).

```
    $wsshell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
    $lnk = $wsshell.CreateShortcut($ShortcutFile)
    $lnk.WindowStyle = 1
    $lnk.TargetPath = "explorer.exe"
    $lnk.Arguments = $TargetPath
    $lnk.IconLocation = "explorer.exe,0"
    $lnk.save() # This will overwrite the previous link if it existed
```

Answer (score 5):

```
New-Item -itemtype symboliclink -Path "PathWhereYouWantToPutShortcut" -name "NameOfShortcut" -value "PathOfWhatYourTryingToLinkTo"
```

[New-Item Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-item?view=powershell-7.1)

Comment: What's the benefit of using `New-Item` over `New-Object`, as done in the accepted answer from four years ago?

Comment: For me. Easier to read.

Comment: This requires admin privileges to execute

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this when creating a shortcut to a directory that didn't exist.  If I simply created the directory ahead of time, then the shortcut worked correctly.

Comment: Yeah, that’s what happened. The thing is that it was done intentionally. I was trying to use it like a Linux symbolic link.